# geolocation.getCurrentPosition does not work in edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I first check `if ('geolocation' in navigator)` and that returns `true`.

I then have a button that when clicked, fetches the user's position using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` like this:

```
const getLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      // stuff
    });
};
```

This works both in Chrome and in Firefox but not in Edge.

When I click the button the first time the browser asks for permission, then it remembers it (allow).
But when I try to `console.log(position)`, the console prints `undefined`.
When I `console.log(navigator.geolocation)` it logs the `geolocation` prototype correctly.. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are using windows check if your location permission is enabled.

Comment: @AliBeyit oh my god that's it, I'm so stupid thank you! If you want to put two lines as answer I'll accept it gladly!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows permissions for location is the answer.